# Java sub form with generic type

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, parameters

I have the **Form** classes like this

```java
@Data
public class Form<T> {
    private T dynamicSubForm;
    private String firstName;
    private Short age;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class SubForm1 {
    private String nickname;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Data
public class SubForm2 {
    private Short height;
    ...
}
```

and I have RestController like this

```java
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping(“/form1”)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getForm1(Form<SubForm1> form) {
        form.getDynamicSubForm().getNickname(); // Error occurs here that type of form.dynamicSubForm is "Object" instead of "SubForm1".
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(“/form2”)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getForm2(Form<SubForm2> form) {
        form.getDynamicSubForm().getHeight(); // Error occurs here that type of form.dynamicSubForm is "Object" instead of "SubForm2".
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

My question is how to instantiate the dynamicSubForm with the target generic type.

Comment: What does the method `getDynamicSubForm` in class `Form` look like? It's return type should be `T`, not `Object`.

Comment: I am confused by this - `public class ResponseEntity<String> getForm1(Form<SubForm1> form)`. Did you perhaps mean creating a method(`static` keyword instead of `class`, or nothing at all)?

Comment: @Jesper Looks like he is using lombok(`@Data`), so method should be correctly generated with return type `T`. Still, it would be best if we get confirmation from OP, since i am guessing.

Comment: @Jasper I am sorry to ask the question with unclear detail. I have used `Lombok` to generate Getter and Setter methods. Thanks @Chaosfire for your guessing.

Comment: @Chaosfire I am sorry about the wrong detail. I would like to update it.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the problem is that Java generics will be erased at runtime.
You can solve this problem by constructing methods.
Provide a lunch structure and a parameter structure for the form.

```
public Form(){}
public Form(Form form, Class cls){
  this.dynamicSubForm = (cls) form.getDynamicSubForm;
}
```

Comment: I will try and reply the result to you again.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion by refine your code like this `public class Form<T> { private T dynamicSubForm; private String firstName; private Short age; public Form(Form from, Class cls) { this.dynamicSubForm = (cls) form.getDynamicSubForm(); }}` but it shows "cls cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).